# How to mitigate and/or repair concrete frets (slab edge wetting)

Tags: repair, concrete, waterproofing, concrete-block

A building engineer made a report of problems with our property. One issue raised was "slab edge wetting" by which the building engineer meant that the concrete slab on which the house is built is being exposed to moisture, which is sucked in via capillary action to distort and weaken the cement. The report recommends there should be a waterproof (plastic) barrier wherever the concrete slab's sides would come into contact with earth.

Has anyone dealt with such a problem before? Is fixing this a simple matter of digging at the edges of the concrete slab where concrete fretting is visible and shoring up the plastic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plastic sheets designed for lining foundations have studs that provide ventilation near the concrete:

[image: studded foundation liner]

There are also sheets available that insulate.